# Maintain Finder's file lock during rsync?

Tags: finder, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to keep two drives in sync. I use the `--archive` flag which is meant to maintain permissions. However, files which are "locked" in Finder do not show as locked after the `rsync` operation is complete. How can I replicate the Finder lock during `rsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `rsync` that macOS provides is about 15-years old and doesn't handle preserving file flags supported by `chflags` (e.g. `UF_IMMUTABLE` or "Locked" as set with `chflags uchg`).

Current versions of [rsync](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/) have:

> --fileflags This option causes rsync to update the file-flags to be the same as the source files and directories (if your OS supports the chflags(2) system call).

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and update `rsync` to a modern version with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew install rsync
```

If you are doing a remote transfer, both the sending and receiving hosts must support `--fileflags`, obviously.

However, if the necessary version of `rsync` is not in the default
remote-shell's PATH (i.e. `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`), the path to the requisite version must be specified. This is done with the `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` option.

For example:

```
rsync --fileflags -avz ${HOME}/ remotehost:${HOME}
```

errors when the remote host's default `rsync` doesn't support `--fileflags`:

> rsync: on remote machine: --fileflags: unknown option
>
> rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(1337) [server=2.6.9]
>
> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
> rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]

Assuming the requisite `rsync` is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, this is resolved with:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync --fileflags -avz ${HOME}/ remotehost:${HOME}
```